# circular reference in recruitment database design

Tags: database-design

design

[image]

So I need to design database for a recruitment scenario. There are 7 tables consist of :

- Applicant : for applicant data
- Position : for position data
- Skill : for skill data
- Applicant skill : list of applicants' skills
- Position skill : list of skills needed for positions
- Vacancy : list of vacancies
- Application : list of application data

I've been told that my design has a circular reference. I searched for some design example  but didn't find any suitable with my case. All the tables are needed and can't be removed. I can't come up with other idea.

how do I get rid of the circular reference? thank you.

Comment: 1. In a comment you say you say " the Jobtitle table only refer to the Position table". Does Application also? Please include all referenced tables. 2. Does a Position JobtitleID have to also appear in Application? If so, you have left out a FK. Does an Application JobtitleID have to also appear in Position? If so, you have left out a FK. Such FKs affect circularity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing circular here, the only obvious problem you may have is not enforcing alternate keys,in diagrams these are usually marked as `AK` -- use `UNIQUE NOT NULL` to create them.

Here are candidate keys for the three tables.

```
ApplicantSkill {APPLICANT_ID, SKILL_ID, APPLICANT_SKILL_ID}
           KEY {APPLICANT_ID, SKILL_ID}
           KEY {APPLICANT_SKILL_ID}

PositionSkill {POSITION_ID, SKILL_ID, POSITION_SKILL_ID}
          KEY {POSITION_ID, SKILL_ID}
          KEY {POSITION_SKILL_ID}

Application {APPLICANT_ID, VACANCY_ID, APPLICATION_ID}
        KEY {APPLICANT_ID, VACANCY_ID}
        KEY {APPLICATION_ID}
```

You have introduced surrogate keys (additional _ID) and chosen them as primary for these tables,
but have omitted others (AK) -- extremely prone to errors, easy to create duplicates, redundancy
and contradiction.

And that `JOB_TITLE_ID` should be removed from the `Application`, it looks like
there is dependency `{POSITION_ID} --> {JOB_TITLE_ID}` so it may go out of sync and create contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

As you've presented it here, your design does *not* have any circular references.

- Applicant, Skill, and Position have no references.
- Applicant Skill, Position Skill, and Vacancy refer only to the above.
- Application refers only to the above.
- and that's it.

So you have nothing to fix.

(Note: I'm ignoring the "Jobtitle ID" thing, since the relevant table does not appear in your diagram. But it doesn't seem like that table would depend on any of these, anyway.)

Comment: yes, the Jobtitle table only refer to the Position table. Will the design create data inconsistency threat or redundancy when querying with JOIN? thank you so much for answering

Comment: Wait a sec -- the Jobtitle table refers to the Position table? In that case you *do* have a circular dependency, because the Position table refers to the Jobtitle table. Why are those separate tables?

Comment: I'm sorry my mistake. I mean Position table refers to the Jobtitle. So FK jobtitle id in Position table is referring to jobtitle id in Jobtitle table. and nothing else.. The thing is i'm confused because someone said that this design will create redundancy and will degrade the performance when querying JOIN. It's because all the table are connected with no end.

Comment: This could only be considered to be a potential problem if you were going to execute a query that included all of those tables, and which joined all of them using those relationships. If you're not going to do that, then it could not be at all relevant.

Answer (score 0):

What you are worry about? Skill table on top of you model and it's undepended.